# How to structure my app using MVP with rxjava and retrofit to get data out of Observables?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

So I'll try to keep this question as to-the-point as possible, but it will involve code snippets that traverse an entire codepath.

For context, I am fairly new and completely self-taught for Android dev, so please notify me of any clear misunderstandings/poor organization throughout. The main focus of the question is bug I am experiencing now, which is that, after a network request, the variable that was supposed to be set as a result of that network request is null, because the code moved forward before the network request completed.

Here is my activity method. It is supposed to populate the `mFriends` variable with the result of `mUserPresenter.getUserList()`, which is (unfortunately) `null`:

```
/**
 * Grabs a list of friends, populates list with UserAdapter
 */
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mUserPresenter = new UserPresenter();
    mFriends = mUserPresenter.getUserList();
    if (mGridView.getAdapter() == null) {
        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), mFriends);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        ((UserAdapter)mGridView.getAdapter()).refill(mFriends);
    }

}
```

Here is how I am structuring my `UserPresenter` method `getUserList`:

```
public List<User> getUserList()
{
    ApiService.get_friends(this);
    return mUserList;
}
```

The real magic happens in the `ApiService` class:

```
public static void get_friends(final UserPresenter userPresenter){
    ApiEndpointInterface apiService = prepareService();
    apiService.get_friends().
        observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            new Action1<List<User>>()
            {
               @Override
               public void call(List<User> users) {
                  userPresenter.setList(users);
               }
            }
        );
}
```

My thinking was, that by calling `userPresenter.setList(users)` in `ApiService`, that would set `mUserList` to the response from the api request. However, instead, `mUserList == null` at the time that `getUserList` responds.

Any ideas of how I can structure this?

Comment: RxJava aside, the first thing you need to have is a blocking network request. I don't use Retrofit so I can't tell about it. But it would be nice to be able to wrap it in something that returns a Future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also started to learn something similar. Here, I would rather use callbacks.

In your presenter,

```
public void setList(List<User> users) {
    yourView.setUserList(users);
}
```

And your activity which implements a view (MVP)

```
@Override
public void setUserList(List<User> users) {
    ((UserAdapter)mGridView.getAdapter()).refill(mFriends);
}
```

Also, check that retrofit is not returning null list.

I have a made a small app when I was learning about all this. It fetches user data from GitHub and shows in a list. I was also working with ORMLite and Picasso so some db stuff is there. Dagger Dependency is also used (but you can ignore that). Here's the [link](https://github.com/jayrambhia/DaggerTest).

Here's how my Presenter behaves:

```
private DataRetrieverImpl dataRetriever;

@Override
public void getUserList(String name) {
    dataRetriever.getUserList(name);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(DataRetrieverEvent event) {
    UserList userList = (UserList)event.getData();
    mainView.setItems(userList);
}
```

`DataRetrieverImpl` works as a module (sort of).

```
private DataRetriever dataRetriever; 
restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(SERVER_END_POINT).build();
dataRetriever = restAdapter.create(DataRetriever.class);

public void getUserList(final String name) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getting user list for: " + name);

    Observable<UserList> observable = dataRetriever.getUserList(name);

    Log.i(TAG, "subscribe to get userlist");
    observable.subscribe(new Action1<UserList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(UserList userList) {

            eventBus.post(new DataRetrieverEvent("UserList", userList));

            // save to database
            for (User user : userList.getItems()) {
                Log.i(TAG, user.getLogin());
                try {
                    dbHelper.create(user);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

And `DataRetriever` is interface for retrofit. I'm sorry for the naming confusion.

```
public interface DataRetriever {

    @GET("/search/users")
    public Observable<UserList> getUserList(@Query("q") String name);

}
```

Any my Activity,

```
@Override
public void setItems(final UserList userList) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UserAdapter userAdapter = (UserAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter();
            userAdapter.setUserList(userList);
            userAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, userAdapter.getItemCount());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response! I ended up moving a little bit in this direction